# Ubuntu server very slow out of the blue sky (Rails, passenger, nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, performance, phusion-passenger

I run Ubuntu server 8.04 on Linode with multiple Rails apps under Passenger + nginx.
Today I've noticed it takes quite a lot of time to load a page (5-10 secs). And it's not only websites, ssh seems to be affected too.

Having no clue why this may be happening, I started to check different things. I checked how the log files are rotated, I checked if there's enough free disk space and memory. I also checked IO rate, here's the output:

```
$ iostat

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.17    0.00    0.02    0.57    0.16   99.07

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
xvda              2.25        39.50        16.08     147042      59856
xvdb              0.00         0.05         0.00        192          0
xvdc              2.20        25.93        24.93      96530      92808
xvdd              0.01         0.12         0.00        434         16
xvde              0.04         0.23         0.35        858       1304
xvdf              0.37         0.31         4.12       1162      15352
```

Rebooting didn't help either.
Any ideas where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on a 'Linode' (I have one too) you're subject to load conditions on the physical host as well. The load on the host will not be reflected in tools like `top` or `iostat`. Go to the Linode dashboard and look at the host stats. That represents the physical server that your virtual instance is running on.

Linode lets you request a move if you feel you're on a server with another user that is hogging physical resources.

Please also include your memory stats swap vs cache vs buffers, etc... (the top section of `top` works well)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check the health of your DNS servers (dig something.com and check the query time).

Jacked up DNS can also affect websites, ssh, etc.